# pretty links using htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a wordpress site and i use some custom pages...in one of that pages i use this url to show content:

http://www.formacao.com.pt/formacao/?id=87&nome=excel-2013-macros-e-vba/

and i want that the url looks like this:

http://www.formacao.com.pt/formacao/87/excel-2013-macros-e-vba/

If someone could help me should be great...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Apache and have mod_rewrite installed and enabled, this should work.

```
Redirect 301 http://www.formacao.com.pt/formacao/?id=87&nome=excel-2013-macros-e-vba/ http://www.formacao.com.pt/formacao/87/excel-2013-macros-e-vba/
```

HTH!

=C=

Answer (score 0):

Just check [this tutorial][http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks] from the Wordpress Codex to activate mod_rewrite on your .htaccess file for Apache or with Nginx. You'll have beautiful PATHINFO links!

#### TL;DR

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

in your `.htaccess` file (for Apache).